# WPF Cовместно используемые свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Помогите разобраться как работают совместно используемые свойства зависимостей и в чём отличие от прикрепляемых свойств?

Например, код `TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty = TextElement.FontFamilyProperty.AddOwner(
typeof(TextBlock))` создаёт совместно используемое свойство. В чём преимущество от их использования? Почему просто не прикрепить свойство `TextElement.FontFamilyProperty` к `TextBlock`?

Comment: Ну вроде в MSDN в описании метода DependencyProperty.AddOwner более-менее все понятно расписано. *Почему просто не прикрепить свойство TextElement.FontFamilyProperty к TextBlock?* — ну так не удобно же, вместо просто FontFamily писать каждый раз TextElement.FontFamily

Comment: Т.е. по сути прикрепляется свойство зависимостей так, что выглядит как собственное свойство элемента. Но при этом если элемент `Control` совместно использует свойство `TextElement.FontFamily`, как и `TextBlock`, то при задании значения этого свойства в родительском `Control`, дочерний элемент `TextBlock` унаследует это значение.

Comment: Нет, наследование значения свойства от родительского элемента это другое, оно делается с помощью указания `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits`

Comment: Но да, эти вещи связаны, т. к. `TextBlock` не является наследником `Control`, но им обоим нужно это свойство, поэтому оно вынесено в отдельный класс и добавлено к ним с помощью `DependencyProperty.AddOwner`

Comment: Читал, что если применить стиль установки значения `TexBlock.FontFamily`, то это повлияет и на `Control.FontFamily`. А каким образом это вообще может происходить?

Comment: Если заглянуть внутрь самого механизма, то все соответствия значений и свойств зависимостей хранятся внутри каждого класса `DependencyObject`. А какое внутреннее различие будет между регистрируемыми и совместно используемыми свойствами? Пожалуй, это ключевой вопрос.

Comment: *Читал, что если применить стиль установки значения TexBlock.FontFamily, то это повлияет и на Control.FontFamily. А каким образом это вообще может происходить?* — ну так они ссылаются на одно и то же DP фактически (`TextElement.FontFamilyProperty`), так что такое поведение логично и ожидаемо.

Comment: *А какое внутреннее различие будет между регистрируемыми и совместно используемыми свойствами?* — никакого, значение будет храниться там, где объявлено оригинальное DP

Comment: "_значение будет храниться там, где объявлено оригинальное DP_" - но мы не создаём объект `TextElement`. Значение разве не будет храниться в `TextBlock`?

Comment: Вы забываете, что все DP хранятся в *статических* полях. Экземпляр не нужен

Comment: Вы правы... Но как тогда организовано хранение значений свойств зависимостей? Ведь у каждого экземпляра своё значение каждого свойства.

Comment: Что то вроде таблицы сопоставления ссылок на экземпляры, id свойств и их значения?

Comment: Что-то вроде словаря, где ключом является сам объект

Comment: _Читал, что если применить стиль установки значения TexBlock.FontFamily, то это повлияет и на Control.FontFamily. А каким образом это вообще может происходить? — ну так они ссылаются на одно и то же DP фактически_ — всё таки почему так происходит? Ведь стиль для `TextBlock` не может быть применён к `Control`. А на стороне класса, который зарегистрировал свойство есть разделение значений для каждого объекта.

Comment: _Вы забываете, что все DP хранятся в статических полях. Экземпляр не нужен_ — Прикрепляемые свойства тоже так?

Comment: Все DP хранятся в статических полях

Comment: *А на стороне класса, который зарегистрировал свойство есть разделение значений для каждого объекта* — ну так здесь на первый план выходит наследование значений DP от родительского элемента. *всё таки почему так происходит? Ведь стиль для TextBlock не может быть применён к Control.* — не может, но когда вы устанавливаете значение свойства `Control.FontFamily`, фактически устанавливается значение AP `TextElement.FontFamily`, потом, когда стилизуется какой-то внутренний TextBlock, то он смотрит в этот AP и по механизму наследования значений получает значение из этого родительского Control

Comment: Вот кстати, если не указывать у стиля `TargetType`, то его можно будет применить к любому элементу и тогда в нем можно установить `Control.FontFamily`, фактически установив при этом `TextElement.FontFamily` и если применить стиль к TextBlock, то он увидит это значение. Таков механизм работы DP, заложенный проектировщиками фреймворка. Если вы хотите знать конкретные детали реализации, то я не могу вам предложить ничего лучше, чем заглянуть в исходники, благо, они общедоступны.

Comment: _Все DP хранятся в статических полях_ - я не это имел ввиду. Значение хранится в классе, который зарегистрировал свойство или в классе, к которому оно прикрепляется?

Comment: _не может, но когда вы устанавливаете значение свойства Control.FontFamily, фактически устанавливается значение AP TextElement.FontFamily_ - а дак оно прикрепляемое? Тогда вообще всё понятно.

Comment: *Значение хранится в классе, который зарегистрировал свойство или в классе, к которому оно прикрепляется?* — значение хранится в экземпляре DP, который записан в static readonly поле

Comment: _значение хранится в экземпляре DP, который записан в static readonly поле_ — ...которое находится в каком классе из? Дак а кстати значения же вроде как хранятся в словаре вы писали. Где есть соответствие ссылок на объекты, id свойств и значения. А словарь этот находится в членах `DependencyObject`.

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я думаю вам стоит оформить полноценный ответ.

Comment: А что я там напишу?

Comment: Ответ на вопрос.